# Form is not getting submitted when all validation is completed - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate form so when it is validated, i should see the message from the alert and the fields become clear. Though on submitting in below code 'isfformValid==true' is not getting executed after i fill all info properly in the form. Any idea.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('create-account-form');
const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

    validateForm();

    if (isFormValid == true) {
        alert("form submitted"); // this is not called and it goes to prevent default
        form.submit();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});

function isFormValid() {
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-group');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container) => {
        if (container.classList.contains('error')) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function validateForm() {
    //USERNAME
    if (usernameInput.value.trim() == '') {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name can not be empty');
    } else if (usernameInput.value.trim().length < 5 || usernameInput.value.trim().length > 15) {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name must be min 5 and max 15 charecters');
    } else {
        setSuccess(usernameInput);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="create-account-form" action="" method="">

 
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="username">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Name" name="username">
          
            <p>Error Message</p>
        </div>
        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
      
            <p>Error Message</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: you check for isFormValid == true but there's no piece of code populating it. Maybe in that case isFormValid() == true was more appropriate.

Comment: @Diego De Vita is right; `isFormvalid` is a function, but `isFormValid()` calls the function and returns.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita  That did not helped by using isFormValid() as a function.

Comment: it worked indeed, was a small mistake. Thanks